# How to translate shipping method titles

Tags: magento2, localisation, magento-2.2.5, translate

I need to change the text for a shipping method title.

Currently we have

Federal Express

Express Saver

I would like this to say Express Saver (3 Day Delivery) instead of Express Saver on the shopping cart/check out pages.

I have added this line to my custom themes translation file however it doesn't work. Where can I edit this text? I obviously don't want to modify the core fedex module files.

```
/home/website/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/i18n/en_US.csv

"Express Saver","Express Saver (3 Day Delivery)",module,Magento_Fedex
```

I also tried putting the string here with no success,

```
/home/website/public_html/app/i18n/en_US.csv

"Express Saver","Express Saver (3 Day Delivery)",module,Magento_Fedex
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the file,

```
/home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/module-fedex/i18n/en_US.csv
```

To a random app under,

```
/home/website/public_html/app/code/vendor/extensionname/i18n/en_US.csv
```

And the new translations worked.